# How to ignore 401 unauthorized error from webrequest to get website status

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I am writing an application to check the status of some internal web applications. Some of these applications use Windows authentication. When I use this code to check the status, it throws `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`. Which is understandable because I haven't provided any credentials to the webiste so I am not authorized.

```
WebResponse objResponse = null;
WebRequest objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(website);
objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
```

Is there a way to ignore the 401 error without doing something like this?

```
WebRequest objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(website);

try
{
    objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    //Catch and ignore 401 Unauthorized errors because this means the site is up, the app just doesn't have authorization to use it.
    if (!ex.Message.Contains("The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."))
    {
        throw;
    }                    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'ignore' here, move on to the next page?

Comment: It probably won't help with the exception at all, but you should be doing a HEAD request as it is lighter and handles this situation well.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Either a property that makes the webrequest not throw an exception or to just swallow the exception like I have above.

Comment: @M.Babcock Do you have a link to an example or how to use that?

Comment: @guanome - [First hit from google](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/asp-net/2c13cafc-be1c-4dd8-9129-f82f59991517/the-lowly-http-head-request.aspx), though the only line that matters is `request.Method = "HEAD";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the server is down or unreachable you will get a timeout exception. I know that the only way to handle that is with a try/catch.

I'm quite sure this is the case for most errors (401/404/501), so: No, you can't ignore (prevent) the exceptions but you will have to handle them. They are the only way to get most of the StatusCodes your App is looking for.

Answer (score 21):

I would suggest to try this:

```
        try
        {
            objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            objResponse = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        }
        finally
```

The WebException has the response all information you want.

Answer (score 3):

The short of it is you'll want to check the `myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode` for the status code and act accordingly.

Sample code from [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode.aspx):

```
public static void GetPage(String url) 
    {
        try 
          { 
                // Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL. 
                HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
                // Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for a response.
                HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(); 
                if (myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                   Console.WriteLine("\r\nResponse Status Code is OK and StatusDescription is: {0}",
                                        myHttpWebResponse.StatusDescription);
                // Releases the resources of the response.
                myHttpWebResponse.Close(); 

            } 
        catch(WebException e) 
           {
                Console.WriteLine("\r\nWebException Raised. The following error occured : {0}",e.Status); 
           }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe following Exception was raised : {0}",e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The exception is thrown at `objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();`, so I can't check the response because the response never gets set. If you mean in the exception, it will give me a `ProtocolError`, so I'll still have to sift through the exception message to see what the status code actually was.